Is the the standard model of physics related to the fibonacci sequence?
I know this is a physics question, however I am unable to ask questions, on that site because of confused questions I ask, when I am unwell and the moderators will not let me ask anything further.
So I am asking on this site, because I know that the discipline of philosophy has interest not only by those describing themselves as philosophers, but also by physicists, computer scientists, etc.
My question, which I have tried to research but have, however, found little information about.
I was hoping that this community may be able answer this question.
If you reduce everything to a singularity at the 'beginning', at the moment of the event of origin of time, surely it naturally follows that every event afterwards formed a sequence. The fibonacci sequence is regarded as, a natural sequence and is found in the natural world.
Does this natural sequence have anything to do with the emergence of dimensions from this singularity and the emergence of what is considered the standard model of particle physics?

"Well that also sounds very mathematical and beyond the realm of understanding of plebs like me." --- I don't think you should close yourself off to mathematics, particularly not if you're interested in things like physics and the Fibonacci sequence! Like... I think one "issue" here is maybe that you're trying to fit something you don't (yet) have the math to understand into the math framework you do understand. But you can see how that won't produce good outputs.

(Obviously, learning all of physics up to a graduate-level understanding of the standard model is a huge undertaking. But a start could be fun in itself! A mathematical understanding of special relativity requires only brushing up on calculus. For QM/statistical mechanics, you'd need to acquaint yourself with the basics of differential equations and linear algebra. It's an undertaking, and it likely won't answer the "unanswerable" questions like "where does the standard model come from", but I think the process itself is rewarding if you can find time and energy for it!)

@Kaia I have some education in calculus and algebra. There had to be a sequence in the events of the universe and objects such as those described by the standard model of physics  My question is speculative that the origin of the universr could follow a natural sequence in the emergence of these objects within the universe that appears in itself in nature. Biology is a natural result of the universe and since in biology there is this pattern so why not the universe?

Fibonacci numbers have been detected mostly in biology, see Fibonacci sequence.
You also find in the internet a paper by El Naschie “The Fibonacci code behind super strings and P-Branes. An answer to M. Kaku’s fundamental question”, see El Naschie.
I have not yet read the paper. Anyhow, super-strings and P-Branes are rather speculative objects.

Thanks for the referral Jo :-)

It was probably a whimsical question any how....


confused questions I ask when I am unwell a

Well, I hope you're all better now.
Dimensions are just directions you can move in. They're all indistinguishable except for these attributes. The first 2 are boring and the last 3  are unexpected:

They share a common metric. That is, vector rotation is possible between the dimensions.

The basis vectors are perpendicular. Their inner product is null.

Length in one dimension can be negative with respect to the others. For instance, Einstein's spacetime interval metric explicitly defines elapsed time as negative spatial distance. That is, to get the absolute (4D Lorentz-invariant)  distance between two events, you subtract the elapsed time from the distance between the events. Time is negative space. See, that was unexpected.

The metric in one dimension can be hyperbolic with respect to another dimension. I prefer to think of this as ordinary inversion, like turning a flat sheet inside out through a hole in the middle. (Technically, we're talking about a Riemann sphere projection).

Dimensions can scale differently. It appears that in 5 of the 11 dimensions, the diameter of the universe is on the Planck scale. This is where strings live. It's the space in which they vibrate -- though its much more useful to think of it as rotation around an imaginary axis.


There is one other kind of dimension, one in which all vectors have zero length. You might wonder why that matters, but it's where photons exist.
The path through spacetime of anything that only exists in a null dimension is called a null surface. Event horizons, light cones, and photons are null surfaces.
Other than than that, the dimensions are indistinguishable. The Fibonacci sequence don't enter into it.

Well that also sounds very mathematical and beyond the realm of understanding of plebs like me. You should be proud of your self. Thanks also for the sincerity with your expression of concern for my well being, it means so much to me

No, it shockingly simple to understand. Feynman's genius was seeing how simple everything is and explaining how simple it is. But he didn't use jargon. He never said "massive object;" he said "stuff." I show how simple it is on my site. I even have links called "Any little kid can understand hypergeometric rotation" and "Any little kid can understand tensor calculus." Click "about me" at the bottom of my profile.

And BTW, Einstein never walked into a bar and announced that he's smarter than anyone in the room. Only stupid people pay attention to things like that. I wish I was the stupidest person in the world so I could ask questions about hyperbolic geometry to the old lady who sells firewood https://luxifuxcom.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/abstrusegoose.com-3.png

I have a confession to make i thought you were being insincere in your answer I suffer from paranoid schizophrenia and can get confused easy and my response was insincere now having looked at the information on your profile I have to apologise for my insincerity and sarcasm which I hope you will forgive me for. You have an interesting mind which must give you more clarity than tyipical minds when addressing the physical. I have problems with emotion too and are socially awkward. I hope you will accept my apology


i thought you were being insincere in your answer == Yeah, well, nobody else understands anything I say either. >  I suffer from paranoid schizophrenia == yeah, well I suffer from disabling autism, nice to meet you. Autism means  I don't want  these kinds of creepy interactions that normal people call friendly conversations. Get well soon!


My sister was a specialist in people that fall under the spectrum. You take care of yourself for what it's worth.

Thanks for this explanation, it is very useful and clear. FYI I am a friendly conversation enthusiast and I hope you have other enthusiasms that can make you happy- whatever your definition of that might be. best regards, Niels
